# RDBMS in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables:

1. `Cartoon` containing P_Name,U_Of_Pack,Weight,No_Cart,No_Pack,Tot_weight
2. `Product` containing P_Name,U_Of_Pack,Weight,No_Cart,No_Pack,Tot_weight

When any changes in the `Product` table are made to No_Cart, No_Pack, Tot_weight columns, these values should be subtracted from the same column's of `Cartoon` table & the updates should be applied in the `Cartoon` table (remaining column values).

Comment: Two tables with the exact same fields looks like a design error to me.

Comment: @David W. Fenton - Not necessarily. We don't have enough contextual info to make that call and I have worked on enterprise apps that required similar types of operations.

Comment: @alex9999 - what exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: @Jason Snelders: I said "LOOKS like a design error" not "IS a design error", so I think I allowed for the possibility of it being an appropriate design.

Comment: I'd agree though - first thing to review is whether the database is appropriately normalised and whether that can be changed. It _might_ be fine as is but it doesn't sound like it.

Comment: If the question truly is, "RDBMS in ms access?" then the answer is, "No."

Answer (score 0):

MS Access **does not support triggers** on tables.

It would almost seem that *Cartoon* can be made up of a *Query* using *Product* instead of an actauls table. This will then still give you *live* results from the *Product* table.

If this is not the case, you would have to create an additinal query to update the *Cartoon* table each time you update the *Product* table.

Comment: A2010 does add table-level data macros that can in fact be used like triggers -- something to look forward to!

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments to the question, to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume there is no design error I think we'd also need to assume that the columns common to both tables (all of them, it would appear) represent a key, in which case you could use the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` referential action on the referencing table `Cartoon`.